# Simple ODataClient Date Filter

Tags: odata

Trying to filter data on datetime field like this:

```
.Filter(p => p.ShiftId == shift.ShiftId && p.ScheduledDate == cell.Date)
```

gives ODataException

If I call the OData controller by hand in the browser it seems to work

```
http://host/odata/DepartmentShifts?$expand=Shift&$filter=StartTime eq 1900-01-01T11:30:00Z
```

Somehow the datetime gets not configured right. Do I need to configure something on the client for this....
I'm using UWP as a client.

Comment: Please provide the exception message and stack trace.  Also, your examples are filtering on two different properties (`ScheduleDate` and `StartTime`).

Comment: DateTime or DateTimeOffset types? OData V4 only supports the latter.

Comment: Sorry, My example was another table.
IF ODataV4 Only supports DateTimeOffset then that's the problem for me. The database has DateTime fields. Is there a workaround?

Comment: var dateFilter = cell.Date.ToString("o");
          var filter = $"{ScheduledShift.EntityPropertyNames.ShiftId} eq {shift.ShiftId} and {ScheduledShift.EntityPropertyNames.ScheduledDate} eq {dateFilter}";

if i write the filter as a string it works....... So for me it looks like the simple client doesn't format the uri correctly when i use the typed syntax